# Get Facebook Contacts and other type contact Information From WP7 Contacts Data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have some plain contacts in my phone and I have also configured facebook,google and hotmail in my phone. In my native people hub I can see my phone contacts as well my facebook contacts and others too. I want to get information of all contacts that have phone number. How I can get that from WP7 contacts api.

```
        var Contacts = new Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts();

        // hook up an event handler to retrieve the contacts after we've searched for them on the WP7
        Contacts.SearchCompleted += ContactsSearchCompleted;

        //Start the search asynchronously.
        Contacts.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching in this way is not particularly well suited to searching for contacts which have a value but rather for searching for a contact for a specific value.

You could do mulitple searches for a single character (using the `FilterKind.PhoneNumber` option) and then combine them.

It'll probably be much easier to get all the results (like you have in your code) and then query them directly.

Something like:

```
foreach (var contact in e.Results)
{
    if (contact.PhoneNumbers.Count() > 0)
    {
        // This contact has at least 1 phone number. 
        // Do something approrpiate with it
    }
}
```